# "press" spacebar on website

Tags: browser, keyboard

I am using quite nice timer for measuring my Rubik's Cube solve time: http://mzrg.com/qqtimer/
I want to use it too on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, when I don't have access to computer. Problem is, that site wants you to press space to start and stop timer. Is there possibility to emulate pressing space in Android browser? If this needs to install some specific browser that's fine.

PS. I know there are some Cube timers in market, but I can't find one with all handy statistics that this site has.

Comment: Well, you could...press the space bar? There is one on the keyboard. If the keyboard is "invisible", it might help to long-press the menu button to bring it up (doesn't always work, but is always worth a try).

Comment: Long pressing menu button brings up virtual keyboard, but also "leaves" site and starts entering new site address. So it is not a solution to a problem.

Comment: Oh -- I wasn't aware of that (never used that feature with the web browser). OK, was worth a try though. So except for an external keyboard, I'm out of ideas then... (or maybe Tasker could be used to insert a keystroke? Tasker can do such things, according to its manual, but I never tried).

Comment: This is just html with javascript. Copy it to another site and modify the code (put a button in it).

Comment: @ott-- You mean - modify and store as offline page? That can work...

Comment: You can also use the greasemonkey plugin (in firefox) and simply add it online. The site owner will not be aware of it.